# How does VARIABLE=() { function definition } work in bash

Tags: bash, function

> WARNING - this question is about the Bash before the [shellshock](/questions/tagged/shellshock) vulnerability, due to which it was changed.

---

I have seen something like this in my bash ENV:

```
module=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*` }
```

How does this construct work? What is it called?

I'm not asking about modulecmd, I am asking about the entire construct.

Comment: Are you sure you found it in that exact syntax (especially with the `=` sign)? Because for me, bash doesn't like it. However without the `=` it would be a function definition.

Comment: Yeah, that is how it appears... There are several other examples of that also. Yeah, I tried it out and got an error from bash about it, but I have examples of it in my ENV.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really a function named `module`. It appears in environment variables when you [export](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-export) a function.

```
$ test() { echo test; }
$ export -f test
$ env | sed -n '/test/{N;p}'
test=() {  echo test
}
```

From [bash documentation - export](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-export):

> export
>
> ```
>  export [-fn] [-p] [name[=value]]
> ```
>
> Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment. **If
>   the -f option is supplied, the names refer to shell functions**;
>   otherwise the names refer to shell variables. The -n option means to
>   no longer mark each name for export. If no names are supplied, or if
>   the -p option is given, a list of exported names is displayed. The -p
>   option displays output in a form that may be reused as input. If a
>   variable name is followed by =value, the value of the variable is set
>   to value.
>
> The return status is zero unless an invalid option is supplied, one of
>   the names is not a valid shell variable name, or -f is supplied with a
>   name that is not a shell function.